# Summernote Editor not Initializing on Page

Tags: summernote, html-editor

I am trying to use summernote in my web app, after i followed the steps provided here http://summernote.org/getting-started/#installation

When i test in browser, it only shows the resize handle at the bottom of the editor, toolbars are not loaded at all. I dont know if there is anything outside the steps provided by the sunnernote instructions. Pls help me out cos am stock here, i dont want to use another editor. Thanks for stopping by..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED
I had the bootstrap.js refrenced before jquery.min.js,
all i did was to reference jquery before any other .js file

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reporting. Could you try below link again?

http://summernote.org/getting-started/#installation

Actually I'm creator of summernote. I updated library path with protocol.
If It's still not working, save below contents with index.html and open it with browser again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap, fontawesome) -->
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <!-- include summernote css/js-->
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.7.0/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.7.0/summernote.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="summernote">Hello Summernote</div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks anyway. I gat it working perfectly. You guys are geniuses. Perfect library

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/UzBekNo1/pen/jOGXpXV)

It helped me but it will help you too

[image]

```
<div class="container pt-2">
<div id="makeMeSummernote">

</div>
<div class="mt-2 text-center">    
  <button id="btnToggleStyle" class="btn btn-primary">Toggle Corrected Styles</button></div>
```